# 50x error pages in Nginx logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, error-log

I'm running a Ruby on Rails app with Nginx and I want to measure how many 50x.html pages are served each week. 
How should I find all Nginx's log records that indicate that a 50x.html page was served?

(I want to be able to see if my site is down in the logs for example)

This is my nginx.conf:

```
server {

  #listen 80 default deferred;

  #<ssl>
  listen 443 ssl default;

  ssl on;

  ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-bundle.crt;

  ...

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  location @unicorn {

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http:// unicorn;

  }

  location ~ ^/(assets)/  {

      root /home/livne/app/public;

      gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version

      expires max;

      add_header Cache-Control public;

  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

  client_max_body_size 4G;

  keepalive_timeout 180;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only serve 50x.html pages only when there is actually error and you have configured error_log directive properly.

You should just do

```
wc -l <path_to_error_log_file>
```

To get the required count. 
Otherwise need more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is a proper error_log configuration? (I've included my nginx conf.)